# WooCommerce — непоследовательная индексация заказов

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Проблема:**

Последовательность индексации заказов сбивается вот так: 
идут заказы с 1-20 по-порядку, потом перескакивает на 40 и дальше по порядку какое-то время. И периодически такое происходит. 
Подскажите, если кто сталкивался с подобным или знает принцип по которому проставляется этот индекс.

[image: WooCommerce — непоследовательная индексация]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё верно, так и должно быть.
Номер заказа — это ID записи в базе. ID -  это автоинкрементный [суррогатный ключ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87).
"Пропущенные" ID-шники могут принадлежать ревизиям, черновикам, медиафайлам и пр.

Если хочется подряд, то есть плагины напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers/